# Have I installed Ubuntu or Xubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, lsb-release

I just installed Xubuntu 14.04 LTS on my laptop (in dual boot with Windows 8.1): so why if I write in the terminal `lsb_release -a` the output is this?

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Comment: Because Ubuntu, Xubuntu, and all other derivatives share the same repositories, and the same base system. The difference is mainly in the interface level and software selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is correct, as *mikewhatever* stated in a comment:*"Because Ubuntu, Xubuntu, and all other derivatives share the same repositories, and the same base system. The difference is mainly in the interface level and software selection."*

To check what DE session you are using you can run:

```
$DESKTOP_SESSION
```

Which will display: `xubuntu`

Also you can check:

```
apt-cache policy xubuntu-desktop
```

should result:

```
xubuntu-desktop:
  Installed: 2.180
  Candidate: 2.180
```

Answer (score 0):

Xubuntu is actually Ubuntu with preinstalled Xfce instead of Unity, so the output is correct.